# EXCEL - Lookup a value in an array, return it if it falls into a certain range/bucket

Tags: excel

I have 11 ranges/buckets (40-45, 45-50, 50-55 and etc). I have an array of data. I need to look for a value in that array and return it depending whether or not it falls into a particular range/bucket. Please see the attached picture. I have done this task using IF function, but it is not the best way of doing this. Tried to use Index and Match, but I am doing something wrong.

[image: Array and Buckets]

Comment: What about the 86.8 in row 3, does it get ignored because there is already a value in that bucket for that line?

Comment: You are right, I have just realized that too. I guess I will add one more range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return what you show.  It will return the first fig for each bucket:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D3:$G3,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN($D3:$G3)-MIN(COLUMN($D3:$G3))+1)/(($D3:$G3>=I$1)*($D3:$G3<IF(J$1="",100,J$1))),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Scott! I would never come up with such formuly on my own, that something beyond my Excel skills :-) But it worked perfectly!